# Anyone want to help fix image links?

Tags: discussion

Per [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only), we need to help out to convert non-imgur http images to https. Assuming the images still exist, this is just trivially uploading them to imgur.

Specifically, when you edit the post, the "bad" http image links will show something like this in the preview where you can just click the upload link and follow through:

[image]

If that doesn't happen, most likely because the image no longer exists, we have to try to find a copy somewhere else, maybe via archive.org.

If you'd like to help, just start going through the list in the answer, and edit the answer to mark things completed when you finish them.

Yes, this is going to cause a lot of churn on the front page, but things are broken, so we have to get through it somehow :( Other sites are doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this list by exporting the tasks from [this crowdcrafting project](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/) and finding the cooking ones. And... I took care of all of them!

Note: the links that say `/questions/#####` are actually answers, and the automatically prettified ones are questions.

Completed:

[How to make pretty crêpes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43955)
[Adding 'swirls' to savoury bread dough](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66471)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29658
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1561
[The secret to hash browns / home fries / breakfast potatoes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6667)
[What are the advantages of a lid on a barbeque?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4329)
[What is the orange coloured cream inside McAloo Tikki called and what are its ingredients?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30718)
[Desperately Seeking Chicken Haddies](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16949)
[How do you make General Tso's chicken as generally found in the Eastern USA?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3047)
[Why do we use so much water to cook spaghetti?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14685)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1239
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3774
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18617
[Is there a way to adjust hot spots in a horizontal smoker setup?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16812)
[Troubleshooting a soufflé that collapses during baking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20599)
[What is the name of this style of knife?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73443)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15170
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53619
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49358
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24784
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54127
[How to bake lokum rolls well?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20687)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/47241
[Can anyone identify this type of green tea?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71595)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54744
[What causes dutch oven flavor?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57595)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57293
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43601
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33698
[Distribution of heat using a silicone oven tray](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54428)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46860
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56531
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55478
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33615
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33698
[Nestle Cream "Ashta"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4997)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33481
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35601
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12335
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33615
[What is this fruit?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25460)
[Name the vegetable from Nilgiri hills](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23036)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21588
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34339
[What is macaroni cooked in milk called?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15451)
[How do I remove bitterness from bitter melon](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7849)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1199
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3770
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4525
[How do I cook toast on an Aga?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4635)
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1076